# Kivy: how to add on_release method to floating button (FloatLayout)?

Tags: python, kivy

I added a FloatButton on my screen, but I am unable to associate any on_release actions to it. I suspect the issue is linked to the fact that my FloatButton actually inherits from FloatLayout, so it does not have the on_release property?
Here is my FloatButton definition in the kv file:

```
<FloatButton@FloatLayout>:
    id: float_add_button  # Giving id to button
    size_hint: (None, None)
    text: ''
    btn_size: (70, 70)
    size: (70, 70)
    bg_color: (0.404, 0.227, 0.718, 1.0)
    # pos_hint: {'x': .6}
 
    Button:
        text: float_add_button.text
        markup: True
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: float_add_button.btn_size
        pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': .8} 
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.404, 0.227, 0.718, 1.0)
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

and further down the kv file I assing on_release

```
<MainWindow>:
    name: 'main'

    RelativeLayout:
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        size_hint: 1, 1
        padding: '20sp'
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        # A few buttons here
        #
        #
        #

    FloatButton:
        id: addButton
        text: '+'
        markup: True
        background_color: 1, 0, 1, 0
        pos_hint: {"x":.5,"top":.5}
        on_release:
            print("[TEST] on_release works!")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\gitcanzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 734, in _apply_rule 
     raise AttributeError(key)
 AttributeError: release

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Recipy_project\Recipy\main.py", line 1, in <module>
     from Recipy.app import Recipy
   File "D:\Recipy_project\Recipy\Recipy\app.py", line 21, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file("Recipy/ui/layout.kv")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\gitcanzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 310, in load_file   
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\gitcanzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 412, in load_string 
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\gitcanzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 665, in _apply_rule 
     child.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "C:\Users\gitcanzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "C:\Users\gitcanzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 545, in apply       
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\gitcanzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 741, in _apply_rule 
     raise BuilderException(
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "D:\Recipy_project\Recipy\Recipy\ui\layout.kv", line 590:
 ...
     588:               pos_hint: {"x":.5,"top":.5}
     589:               on_release:
 >>  590:                       print("[TEST] on_release works!")
     591:                       # root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
     592:                       # app.root.current = 'add'
 ...
 AttributeError: release
   File "C:\Users\gitcanzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 734, in _apply_rule 
     raise AttributeError(key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is exactly what you say, your `FloatButton` class is derived from `FloatLayout` not from `Button`, so it does not have the `on_release` event.

One option is to define that custom event in your `FloatButton` class:

```
class FloatButton(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_release')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def on_release(self, *args):
        pass
```

and dispatch it when the internal button is pressed:

```
<FloatButton@FloatLayout>:
    # ...
    Button:
        on_release: root.dispatch('on_release')
```

A complete reproducible example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


kv = '''
<FloatButton@FloatLayout>:
    id: float_add_button  # Giving id to button
    size_hint: (None, None)
    text: ''
    btn_size: (70, 70)
    size: (70, 70)
    bg_color: (0.404, 0.227, 0.718, 1.0)
    # pos_hint: {'x': .6}

    Button:
        on_release: root.dispatch('on_release')
        text: float_add_button.text
        markup: True
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: float_add_button.btn_size
        pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': .8}
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.404, 0.227, 0.718, 1.0)
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos


<MainWindow@RelativeLayout>:
    name: 'main'

    FloatButton:
        id: addButton
        text: '+'
        markup: True
        background_color: 1, 0, 1, 0
        pos_hint: {"right":.5,"top":.5}
        on_release:
            print("[TEST] on_release works!")

MainWindow:
'''


class FloatButton(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_release')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def on_release(self, *args):
        pass


class MainWindow(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow().run()
```

Comment: Your example works very fine for me. Applied to my code however it makes the app run without any error, but nothing happens on release of the button. If it matters, I defined the FloatButton class not in the ` main.py` , but in `ui/widgets.py`

Comment: alright so this works for me if I put the `on_release: print("[TEST] on_release works!")`  part inside the definition of ` FloatButton@FloatLayout` rather than in `MainWindow@RelativeLayout`. Not sure why? Many thanks anyway!